# How to convert below android method to a Recursive Method?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I created 800 Fragment for education software so I cant use `vpPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(800)`. I think I must use a loop to open a `FragmentX(LessonX)` with buttonclicks.
My methods are below I tried all of them and They run slow, opening a `fragmentXYZ` takes 3 minutes or 4 minutes. I want help or want to try recursive method, but I didnt manage converting to recursive method. Any help please? and sorry for my poor English.

```
public void  Mypagermethod_1(int x) {
    final ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public void  Mypagermethod2(int x) {
    final ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    int i=1;
    while(i <= x){
        vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

OR

```
public void  Mypagermethod3(int x) {
    final ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    int i=1;
    do {
        vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        i++;
    } while(i <= x);
}
```

Comment: Whenever I ask a question, My reputation number decreases please dont give me negative I am only a teacher and recruit programmer. I am preparing an education software for my students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the code samples above will have the same performance and changing to a recursive method will make no difference.  The issue is clearly around `vpPager.setCurrentItem(vpPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);`, if that method is slow then it's going to be slow however you call it.

You haven't really given enough information to allow for a more specific answer, you need to debug and see where the time is being taken.  Are you rendering images or anything else that can be palmed off to a separate thread?

Comment: No image rendering but Each fragment has gridview. Gridview cells speak if someone touches  and cells have very small pictures or sentences. and many font adapters are used . First Fragment is MainLessons menu and full of hundred of buttons.(Button1->Lesson1, ,,Button800->Lesson800 )  If I use Mypagermethod, to open a lesson, inside a button click, takes much time. But No problem with swiping left or right horizantal or vertical up ,down. But to open Lesson800  with swipeing , is difficult. Person must swipe  to left , 800 times to open Fragment800.  thank you much for your helping and marks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see what you're doing. You don't have to simulate swiping one page at a time in your method, just call vpPager.setCurrentItem(800).

Comment: for calling vpPager.setCurrentItem(800), vpPager. setOffscreenPageLimit (800) must be written  in a suitable method and  The power of phones and tablets are still weak, all the devices cant manage running or caching  vpPager. setOffscreenPageLimit (800) command.

Comment: I would advise you to read up on the documentation of the ViewPager. The setOffscreenPageLimit is used to set the number of preloaded Fragments in your ViewPager and you should **not** try to set it so high, just call the setCurrentItem directly.

Comment: If fragment layouts are different from each other vpPager.setCurrentItem(0) and vpPager.setCurrentItem(1) runs but not run vpPager.setCurrentItem(x) if x>=2. It gives null point exception

Comment: You'll need to manage the off screen fragments yourself. Think of your view pager as a recording film where the film can be infinite but the projector only displays one frame at a time and has 2 or 3 frames available right next to it for future playback or rewinding. If you manage a window of 5 fragments yourself you can accommodate the 800 fragments while keeping performance up to speed.